# Нужно ли выделять запятыми оборот "словно кленовый лист"?

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

Мощным порывом ветра словно кленовый лист рыбацкую лодку метнуло в маяк.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо переставить сравнительный оборот:

Мощным порывом ветра  рыбацкую лодку, **словно кленовый лист**, метнуло в маяк.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше ставить сравнительный оборот после слов, к которым он относится, тогда и вопрос о его выделении решается просто. Корректно:

**Мощным порывом ветра рыбацкую лодку, словно кленовый лист, метнуло в маяк.**

Comment: Сравнительный оборот на другом конце предложения: Катарсис, растопырив руки, летел в пустоте, как кленовый лист. [Алексей Иванов. Охота на «Большую Медведицу» (1990-1991)]

Comment: @Jasmin Однако оборот стоит после слова *летел*, а не до него. Я не имел в виду непосредственно следом за ним.

Comment: Я хотела сказать, что позиция оборота достаточно свободная, но не любая; сравнительный оборот должен вписываться в структуру конкретного предложения.

Comment: @Jasmin "Должен вписываться в структуру конкретного предложения" => А возможно ли это требование выразить более формально? Я попытался, не знаю насколько удачно...

Comment: "Лодку как кленовый лист": сравнительный оборот относится к одному слову, а в предложении он может занимать разные позиции. Какие-либо формальные рекомендации  здесь давать сложно. В заданном предложении оборот стоял после обстоятельства перед основной частью предложения, такое начало  некорректно, так как трудно понять внутренние смысловые связи.